# My user name appears twice on github even though I have 1 commit?

Tags: github, commit

[image: Two names]

I don't understand why I have 2 names appearing even though I only did 1 commit. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not to do with the number of commits, but the metadata of the latest commit shown. You will be both author and committer. Perhaps were different email addresses used for each of those actions?

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be due to having a `branch` along with the `master branch`

Comment: You've used two different email addresses and GitHub doesn't understand that they both belong to the same individual.  Add all your email addresses to your GitHub profile and verify them.

Comment: I have been using the same email address though and I'm also on the master branch so I don't think it's that either